# Lee lineas de fichero txt y devuelve aquellas que tenga un conjunto de caracteres especificos

Tags: bash, script, shell

He creado un script mi_script.sh que basicamente lee un documento de texto y me devuelve las lineas que contengan la palabra GAP. No obtengo error pero el resultado obtenido no es el que quiero.

Copio y pego mi script. Primer test y segundo test son otras cosas que mi script hace, he copiado mi script completo en cualquier caso.

```
#!/bin/bash




####### First test  #################

# This script ONLY accept GRCh37 build.
# Let's ask the user which build he is going to use and tell him/her that GRCh37 is not available.

read -p "Input genome build GRCh37 or GRCh38: " GENOME

if [[ $GENOME == "GRCh38" ]]; then 
  echo "$GENOME Selected"
  GENOME_OK=True
else 
  echo "Genome ID $GENOME is not supported"
  GENOME_OK=False

fi
echo "Is the Genome ID OK: $GENOME_OK"

####### Second test  #################
# To ask which file is going to be read

echo "please enter filename: "

read filename

if [ -f /Users/.../$filename ];
then
    echo "$filename found."

ALIGNMENT_FILE_OK=True
else
# If file not found in directory, this script will try to download from NCBI

    echo "&filename not found. It will be download for you if found in ncbi./n/n"
    curl 'https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/refseq/H_sapiens/alignments/GCF_000001405.39_knownrefseq_alignments.gff3' -o /Users/.../grch38.gff
fi

echo "Is the Alignment file available: $ALIGNMENT_FILE_OK"
input_file= /Users/.../$filename

# We are going to create function that contains a for loop which reads the alignment gff3 file we downloaded earlier
# and looks for a transcript ID and chromosome ID and reports whether there is a Gap.
# If a Gap is found it will print data about each Exon containing a gap including the CIGAR string.


######## Gap finder.  #####################

function gap_finder() {

#  Open the file using the file handle and read line-by-line

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *"Gap="* ]]
    then
      echo $line
    fi
done < "$ALIGNMENT_FILE"
}

gap_finder(input_file)
```

El resultado que obtengo una salida de lineas todas iguales a la que ponga debajo. Solo cambia el numero de la linea.

/user/.../grch38.gff: line 1: NC_000002.12: command not found

/user/.../grch38.gff: line 2: NC_000002.12: command not found

/user/.../grch38.gff: line 3: NC_000002.12: command not found

/user/.../grch38.gff: line 4: NC_000002.12: command not found

/user/.../grch38.gff: line 5: NC_000002.12: command not found
...

Comment: ¿Por qué algo tan complejo? Con apenas `grep "Gap= fichero` ya lo tendrías.

Comment: @Jan, es que estás usando bash como si fuera otro lenguaje de programación. Por ejemplo, en la llamada a la función `gap_finder(input_file)`, debería ser `gap_finder $input_file`. Dentro de esta función, usas una variable que no haz ni declarado ni inicializado. En es caso, deberías de utilizar la variable `$1` en su lugar, pues es el del primer parámetro que sería el archivo.